# Pandas Flatten a list of list within a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to flatten a column which is a list of lists:

```
    var         var2
0   9122532.0   [[458182615.0], [79834910.0]]
1   79834910.0  [[458182615.0], [9122532.0]]
2   458182615.0 [[79834910.0], [9122532.0]]
```

I want:

```
    var         var2
0   9122532.0   [458182615.0, 79834910.0]
1   79834910.0  [458182615.0, 9122532.0]
2   458182615.0 [79834910.0, 9122532.0]
```

Applying

```
sample8['var2'] = sample8['var2'].apply(chain.from_iterable).apply(list)
```

Gives me:

```
    var1        var2
0   9122532.0   [[, 4, 5, 8, 1, 8, 2, 6, 1, 5, ., 0, ], [, 7, ...
1   79834910.0  [[, 4, 5, 8, 1, 8, 2, 6, 1, 5, ., 0, ], [, 9, ...
2   458182615.0 [[, 7, 9, 8, 3, 4, 9, 1, 0, ., 0, ], [, 9, 1, ...
```

Comment: Standard warning: storing non-scalar elements in Series and DataFrames isn't well-supported and can lead to obscure and hard-to-figure bugs.

Answer (score 7):

**Data:**

```
In [162]: df
Out[162]:
           var                           var2
0    9122532.0  [[458182615.0], [79834910.0]]
1   79834910.0   [[458182615.0], [9122532.0]]
2  458182615.0    [[79834910.0], [9122532.0]]
```

**Solution:** use [np.ravel()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
In [163]: df['var2'] = df['var2'].apply(np.ravel)

In [164]: df
Out[164]:
           var                       var2
0    9122532.0  [458182615.0, 79834910.0]
1   79834910.0   [458182615.0, 9122532.0]
2  458182615.0    [79834910.0, 9122532.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        var=[9122532.0, 79834910.0, 458182615.0],
        var2=[[[458182615.0], [79834910.0]],
              [[458182615.0], [9122532.0]],
              [[79834910.0], [9122532.0]]]
    ))

print(df)

           var                           var2
0    9122532.0  [[458182615.0], [79834910.0]]
1   79834910.0   [[458182615.0], [9122532.0]]
2  458182615.0    [[79834910.0], [9122532.0]]
```

***`np.concatenate`***
You can `apply` `np.concatenate`

```
df.assign(var2=df.var2.apply(np.concatenate))

           var                       var2
0    9122532.0  [458182615.0, 79834910.0]
1   79834910.0   [458182615.0, 9122532.0]
2  458182615.0    [79834910.0, 9122532.0]
```

***w/o `apply`***
This requires that all have the same `2 x 1` shape.  It can always be adapted to another shape.  However, this method still requires that all shapes are consistent.

```
df.assign(var2=np.array(df.var2.tolist()).reshape(-1, 2).tolist())

           var                       var2
0    9122532.0  [458182615.0, 79834910.0]
1   79834910.0   [458182615.0, 9122532.0]
2  458182615.0    [79834910.0, 9122532.0]
```

---

***timing***
*small data*

[image]

*large data*

[image]