# Spark DataFrame flatten a column which is a nested list or a list of sets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am "grouping by" a dataframe based on two keys, `key1`, `key2`. Then I `collect_list` another column `value` which returns a nested list, since that column is already a `Seq` (same applies if the column is a `Set`).

I need to flatten that nested list.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
case class Record(key1: String, key2: String, values: Seq[String])
val ds: Dataset[Record] = spark.createDataset(Seq(
  Record("abc", "bca", Seq("one", "two", "three")),
  Record("abc", "bca", Seq("three", "two", "one")),
  Record("xyz", "xyz", Seq("four", "five", "six"))
))

ds.show(false)
/*
+----+----+-----------------+
|key1|key2|values           |
+----+----+-----------------+
|abc |bca |[one, two, three]|
|abc |bca |[three, two, one]|
|xyz |xyz |[four, five, six]|
+----+----+-----------------+
*/
val firstDf: DataFrame = ds.groupBy($"key1", $"key2").agg(collect_list($"values").as("values"))
firstDf.show(false)
/* Column "value" is a nested list.
+----+----+--------------------------------------+
|key1|key2|values                                |
+----+----+--------------------------------------+
|xyz |xyz |[[four, five, six]]                   |
|abc |bca |[[one, two, three], [three, two, one]]|
+----+----+--------------------------------------+
/*
firstDf.printSchema()
root
 |-- key1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

**Desired result**

Duplicate values are allowed (list semantics). But in some other cases, I *don't need duplicate entries (set semantics)*, so let's make the answer a generic one.

```
+----+----+----------------------------------+
|key1|key2|values                            |
+----+----+----------------------------------+
|xyz |xyz |[four, five, six]                 |
|abc |bca |[one, two, three, three, two, one]|
+----+----+----------------------------------+
Or alternatively:
+----+----+-----------------+
|key1|key2|values           |
+----+----+-----------------+
|xyz |xyz |[four, five, six]|
|abc |bca |[one, two, three]|
+----+----+-----------------+
```

In fact I am looking for a solution like this [Pandas Flatten a list of list within a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216411/pandas-flatten-a-list-of-list-within-a-column).

I have tried to `firstDf.select("values.*")` as per some other posts, but I get:
`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: ArrayBuffer(values);`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is exactly called `flatten`:

```
val firstDf = ds.groupBy($"key1", $"key2").agg(flatten(collect_list($"values")).as("values"))

firstDf.show(false)
+----+----+----------------------------------+
|key1|key2|values                            |
+----+----+----------------------------------+
|xyz |xyz |[four, five, six]                 |
|abc |bca |[one, two, three, three, two, one]|
+----+----+----------------------------------+
```

If you want only distinct items, you can use `array_distinct`:

```
val firstDf = ds.groupBy($"key1", $"key2").agg(array_distinct(flatten(collect_list($"values"))).as("values"))

firstDf.show(false)
+----+----+-----------------+
|key1|key2|values           |
+----+----+-----------------+
|xyz |xyz |[four, five, six]|
|abc |bca |[one, two, three]|
+----+----+-----------------+
```

For older spark versions (< 2.4) you can use a UDF for flattening:

```
def flattenudf = udf((x: Seq[Seq[String]]) => x.flatten)
// if you want distinct elements,
// def flattenudf = udf((x: Seq[Seq[String]]) => x.flatten.distinct)
val firstDf = ds.groupBy($"key1", $"key2").agg(flattenudf(collect_list($"values")).as("values"))
```

Comment: Can you please show the import of the `flatten` method?

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` . It's available since spark 2.4 though.

Comment: :( Any solution for 2.3? Maybe you can change your answer to have a solution for different spark versions..

Comment: @user1485864 see edited answer with a flatten udf.

Comment: Nice! And for <2.4, how to remove duplicates? I found it. ``x.flatten.distinct``

Comment: @user1485864 you can add `.distinct` after `.flatten` in the udf

Answer (score 0):

Another way using the RDD API if you can't use `flatten` and `array_distinct` functions :

```
val final_df = firstDF.rdd.map { 
  r => (r.getString(0), r.getString(1), r.getAs[Seq[Seq[String]]](2).flatten.distinct)
}.toDF("key1", "key2", "values")

final_df.show

//+----+----+-----------------+
//|key1|key2|           values|
//+----+----+-----------------+
//| xyz| xyz|[four, five, six]|
//| abc| bca|[one, two, three]|
//+----+----+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `explode` (which may be problematic if your data is too large) and avoiding `flatten` etc:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.select('key1', 'key2', F.explode('values').alias('values'))
       .groupby('key1', 'key2')
       .agg(F.collect_list('values'))
```

To get distinct values, replace `collect_list` with `collect_set`.

The code is PySpark but something similar should work in Scala too.